# P&T Playa and Var Prefix

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic, solspace-rating

I've got quite a bizarre setup to get the most recent "Rated" entries (Via Solspace Rating Module) and output the related Product & Video to that entry (Which is handled via Playa)

```
{exp:rating:entries
    collection="Video Reviews"
    orderby="rating_date"
    sort="desc"
    limit="1"
    dynamic="no"
}

    {exp:channel:entries channel="entry_video" orderby="date" limit="1" dynamic="off" entry_id="{entry_id}"}

        {title}

        {cf_video_related_products limit="1"}
            {title}
        {/cf_video_related_products}

        {cf_video_related_video limit="1"}
            {title}
        {/cf_video_related_video}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:rating:entries}
```

Now when I run this, it works... Except I get something like this:

> Rating Title
>   Rating Title
>   Rating Title

When really I want it to be:

> Rating Title
>   Product Title
>   Video Title

Now I know what's happening... There is multiple title tags and it's possibly pulling the {title} from the Rating module or the Channel Entries loop for every {title} var.

I thought of changing this, so i use the var_prefix parameter supplied by Playa, but this doesn't work:

```
{exp:rating:entries
    collection="Video Reviews"
    orderby="rating_date"
    sort="desc"
    limit="1"
    dynamic="no"
}

    {exp:channel:entries channel="entry_video" orderby="date" limit="1" dynamic="off" entry_id="{entry_id}"}

        {title}

        {cf_video_related_products limit="1"}
            {title}
        {/cf_video_related_products}

        {exp:playa:children field="cf_video_related_products" limit="1" var_prefix="product"}
            {product:title}
        {/exp:playa:children}

        {exp:playa:children field="cf_video_related_video" limit="1" var_prefix="video"}
            {video:title}
        {/exp:playa:children}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:rating:entries}
```

But all this does is output:

> {product:title}
>   {video:title}

Am I doing something wrong? I've tried `parse="inward"` but that doesn't help neither. Because I thought it might of been the parse order causing this.

Comment: Jason, that should work. Have you tried this without the Ratings module in play?  A reduction test is going to be your best bet in figuring this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like you're using both the field tags and module tags for `cf_video_related_products` playa field.

Try removing the field tag and add the `entry_id="{entry_id}"` parameter to each of the `exp:playa:children` module tags. Typically the module tags defaults to the current entry's ID if within the `exp:channel:entries` tag pair, but that might thrown off because of the nested ratings and entries call.

If that doesn't work, you could always use an embed:

#### Parent Template:

```
{exp:rating:entries
    collection="Video Reviews"
    orderby="rating_date"
    sort="desc"
    limit="1"
    dynamic="no"
}
    
    {embed="tmpl_group/tmpl_name" entry_id="{entry_id}"}

{/exp:rating:entries}
```

#### Child Template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="entry_video" orderby="date" limit="1" dynamic="off" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"}

    {title}

   {exp:playa:children field="cf_video_related_products" entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1" var_prefix="product"}
        {product:title}
    {/exp:playa:children}

    {exp:playa:children field="cf_video_related_video" entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1" var_prefix="video"}
        {video:title}
    {/exp:playa:children}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I'll give this a bash. Ideally I don't want to use an embed.